# On Rent or For Rent?

Tags: prepositions

apartments on rent in Bangalore  or apartments for rent in Bangalore?

Which is correct or what is the difference between the two?!!

Comment: Your two choices are [***for** and **to***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=houses+to+rent%2Chouses+for+rent%2Chouses+on+rent&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chouses%20to%20rent%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chouses%20for%20rent%3B%2Cc0), which mean the same. Native speakers would rarely if ever use ***on** rent* in any context.

Comment: so, it should be for rent!

Comment: Probably, if your advert is aimed at Americans. I think Brits would be more likely to use ***to***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers If the verb is ***rent***, we'd say ***for rent***. The other option is ***to let***, as in "apartments to let". (though since we're Brits, it'd be flats rather than apartments)

Comment: @John: It was because of that *apartment/flat* difference that I specified *houses* in my link above.

Comment: In the US it would be "for rent".  My understanding is that in the UK it would usually be "to let".  I have no idea what it would be in Bangalore.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simply "For Rent" or "To Rent", which are basically the same thing in this context.

I have never heard "On Rent", and doesn't really make sense in my mind.

This website uses "For Rent" for Bangalore.
https://www.commonfloor.com/apartments-for-rent

Answer (score 0):

The Oxford English Dictionary has an example from 1736

> 1736   J. Murray Lett. (1901) 24,   I have got a good convenient house on rent.

They also list "on rent" meaning "at interest", but call it *obsolete, rare*

Comment: But note that "on rent" may well have meant "currently being rented", not "available for renting".